# startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges and Google Analytics screen views

Tags: ios, google-analytics

In my app, I use startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges and it's delegate

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation])
```

gets called appropriately whether the app is in the foreground, the background, suspended or terminated as appropriate.

My question is this: when the app is running in the background and a significant location change event occurs, would this somehow trigger Google Analytics to count a screen view? I want to make sure I'm not seeing phantom counts for my Analytics.